# C# Автоматические свойства vs свойства, передача значений в конструкторе класса

Tags: c#

Пример кода:

```
class MyClassA 
{
   public string A { get; }
   public MyClassA(string a) {
      A = a; //нет ошибки
   }
}

class MyClassB
{
   private string a;
   public string A 
   {
      get {return a}
   }
   public MyClassB(string a) {
      A = a; // Ошибка (cannot be assigned to - it's readonly)
   }
}
```

Почему, я абсолютно не понимаю, почему в случае с автоматическими свойствами только для чтения можно в контрукторе им записывать данные, а в обычные свойства нет?

Comment: потому что в первом случае будет сгенерировано приватное скрытое поле, куда можно писать в конструкторе (компилятор туда подставит приватное сгенерированное поле). Во втором случае никакого поля сгенерировано не будет

Comment: @tym32167   Абсолютно ничего не понял если честно, в моем случае код двух вариантов для меня это шило на мыло.  Что обычное свойство обращается к приватному полю, что автоматическое к приватному но скрытому. Какая разница если в обеих случаях они только для чтения и я в конструкторах обращаюсь именно к свойствам а не полям, и уж тем более никак не к скрытым полям.

Comment: Я вам уже говорил в предыдущем вопросе, зайдите на сайт [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io) и посмотрите во что превращается тот или иной код. В первом случае, в конструкторе у вас будет `сгенерированноеПриватноеПоле = a;`, без использования свойства, а во втором случае такого не будет, ибо вы сами уже управляете всем, аналогом будет `a=a;`.

Comment: А какая разница? что мое поле, что сгенерированное? И почему именно в конструкторе такое происходит, в обычных методах всё как должно быть. <q> В первом случае, в конструкторе у вас будет сгенерированноеПриватноеПоле = a;, без использования свойства</q>  - т.е. явно пропускается полностью свойство и именно только в конструкторе, зачем так?  <q> а во втором случае такого не будет, ибо вы сами уже управляете всем, аналогом будет a=a;</q> - это я не смог проверить т.к. выводит только ошибку на сайте который вы мне скинули, но даже если говорить о том, что вы написали, то это тоже-самое

Comment: Не важно как код выглядит для вас, важно как он выглядит для компилятора. Для компилятора разница есть, вам ее расписали. Не понятно, какого ещё ответа вы ожидаете.

Comment: @Alegro В C# очень много синтаксического сахара, который облегчает вам, программисту жизнь, например простой `foreach`, попробуйте на сайте, что я дал написать его, получите в итоге `while` цикл, который запутанней, чем то, что вы написали. Также и свойства, если все генерируется автоматом, то вам разрешается написать в конструкторе `A = 5`, но "под капотом" это будет иметь уже 2-й ваш вариант, где за вас создадут приватное поле и в него будут заносить это значение, другими словами, там будет `a = 5`. Тоже самое, во 2-м примере вы можете сделать сами, задав значение полю, а не свойству.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Полностью с вами согласен, но дело в том, что в варианте где у меня свойство которое ссылается на мое поле, указано только get и оно возвращает мое же поле, все правильно. Но в случае с автосвойством за меня создается поле, да все верно, вот только я в этом свойстве указал только get, априори "по крайней мере по моей логике" невозможно присваивание т.к. свойство не умеет блока кода с set. То что вы сказали посмотреть на сайте как это происходит, для меня вообще новелла, как это код пропускает свойство с его условным getter, возможно там просто значение return подставлено из св-ва?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При наличии явно определенного свойства для присваивания get-only следует использовать поле, которое считаете нужным. Компилятор не анализирует блок кода геттера, чтобы угадать, что и куда вы хотите присвоить. Компилятор ведет себя строго и однозначно, что от него и требуется.

Вот пример вообще без поля:

```
public string A 
{
    get { return "hello"; }
}
```

Или поле, определенное в другом классе:

```
public string A 
{
    get { return otherClass.a; }
}
```

Или даже так:

```
private string a = "hello";
private string b = "world";
public string A 
{
    get { return a + " " + b; }
}
```

Что по-вашему должен сделать компилятор, когда вы захотите в конструкторе сюда что-то присвоить?

В случае с автосвойством компилятор автоматически подставит поле, сгегерированное при сборке.

Если хотите защитить данные в свойстве от присваивания при наличии явно определенного поля, и присваивать только в конструкторе, используйте `readonly` модификатор доступа для поля.

Comment: Мозги абсолютно перестали соображать, простите если ересь напишу:  **Что по-вашему должен сделать компилятор, когда вы захотите в конструкторе сюда что-то присвоить?** - ничего т.к. нету set в свойстве.   **В случае с автосвойством компилятор автоматически подставит поле, сгегерированное при сборке.** - этому есть логическое объяснение? я бьюсь уже который час чтобы понять логику. В моем понимании - определяешь автосвойство, даешь ему getter а он в этот getter записывает свою сгенерированную переменную как возвращаемую, но никакого set там нету.

Comment: **Если хотите защитить данные в свойстве от присваивания при наличии явно определенного поля, и присваивать только в конструкторе, используйте readonly модификатор доступа для поля.** - это меня и пугает, автосвойство с одним только getter ведет себя как readonly поле. В моем понимании свойства почти идентичны методам, set реагирует на оператор присваивания и возвращает полю значение которое присвоило этому свойству исполняющий код, а get возвращает поле исполняемому коду который вызывает это свойство.

Comment: @Alegro свойство это и есть пара методов, не больше не меньше. Технически это ни что иное, как просто методы. Автосвойство упрощает синтаксис. Гапример публичные автосвойства делают, когда не нужно ничего писать в геттере и сеттере, а нужно только управлять их доступностью, например `get; private set;`, или для удобной сериализации. Если бы get-only свойство нельзя было присваивать, то его вообще нельзя было бы присвоить. Поэтому сделали возможность однократного присваивания. Без нее оно просто не имеет никакого смысла. Никакого set в get-only автосвойстве дейтвительно нет.

Comment: Т.е. 'public string A { get; readonly set; }' где readonly неявно обозначена? Возможно технически это не так, я не знаю. Но логически это именно так по моему мнению. Нужно же как-то объяснить что автоматическое свойство присваивается только в конструкторах

Comment: @Alegro `readonly set` даже не скомпилится, и я не знаю, что это может значить. То что get-only автосвойство можно присваивать в кострукторах, вы узнаёте пока изучаете C#, и дело в том что технически больше нигде такое свойство присваивать нельзя. Присваивание при объявлении это тоже по сути неявный конструктор.